# where can I download ChatGPT with the VOICE feature, for iPhone?

Tags: ios

This journal reports *"OpenAI’s ChatGPT Voice feature is now available to all free users, so you can ditch Siri as your main voice assistant on your iPhone"*
https://techcrunch.com/2023/11/22/forget-siri-turn-your-iphones-action-button-into-a-chatgpt-voice-assistant-instead/

The Apple App store just seems to have the regular text-based chatgpt.  Anyone know what name to find the free spoken voice version under?  Thx.

Comment: ANSWER UPDATE:  OpenAI has updated ChatGPT for the iPhone.  You no longer need to fuss with a custom workflow for the action button.   You switch to spoken mode by clicking on the headphone icon, bottom right of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The apps needed are on the App Store.

If you can’t follow the setup instructions to establish a custom workflow for the button, you might need to open a support ticker with the appropriate app provider:

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chatgpt/id6448311069
- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/shortcuts/id915249334

Right now, this requires an [action button on iPhone 15 Pro Max or iPhone 15 Pro](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/action-button-iphone-15-pro-max-iphe89d61d66/ios) so when you press that hardware button, it triggers the app to take voice recognition.

Comment: You no longer need to change the function of the action button.  There is now a headphone icon visible in the app, permitting spoken I/O.   Things change fast with OpenAI.   Thank you for your helpful answer, bmike.

Comment: Wow @PetervdL I’d encourage you to answer that or edit my post so the TLDR is at the top. And any wrong info is removed. Screen upload of the icon would be 100% awesome